# Set minimum purchase condition ideas needed :)

Tags: solidity, tokens, remix, ico

I am quite the beginner and trying to get my head around things using Remix practice building contracts.

I want to set a minimum total purchase required(amount Tokens)
I am using
 " https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol"
as my starting point.

now i want to require set minimum to get a bonus like

```
// from BokkyPooBah MyToken example:

if (now <= BonusAdded) {   
            tokens = msg.value * 4500;
        } else {
            tokens = msg.value * 3000;
        }
```

Appreciate any advice

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: how to set a minimum investment needed to receive above bonus.

Comment: Minimum investment means? Min amount of tokens? ethers?

Comment: Minimum Tokens bought with Ether to receive the bonus

Comment: EX. You need to buy a minimum of 30000 Tokens @ 3000\Eth to get a 50% bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this helps

```
uint public minLimitToGetBonus = 1000 * (10 ** decimals)
function getToken() public {
    if(balances[msg.sender] > minLimitToGetBonus){
        // give bonus
    }
    else{
        // process normally
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:** 
As per discussion in comments:

```
contract BunusCoin{
    uint minLimitToGetBonus = 1000;
    bool InTime = true;
    uint rate = 3000;

    mapping(address => uint ) public balances;

    function NoMoreHoops() public payable{
        require(InTime);
        uint tokensPurchasing = msg.value * rate ; // no of tokens purchasing
        //  if you want to consider prev balances as well. Uncomment below line
        // totalTokens = balances[msg.sender].safeAdd(tokensPurchasing);
        // else
        uint totalTokens = tokensPurchasing ; 
        // check eligibility for Bonus
        if(totalTokens > minLimitToGetBonus){
             tokensPurchasing = tokensPurchasing .safeMul(1500).safeDiv(100); // 50% bonus
        }
        balances[msg.sender] = safeAdd(balances[msg.sender], tokensPurchasing); 
        _totalSupply = safeAdd(_totalSupply, tokensPurchasing); 
        Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokensPurchasing); 
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou i can see your idea and will play with it .I was thinking i need to add condition to this function in the solidity crowdsale contract.                                ´ function _updatePurchasingState(address _beneficiary, uint256 _weiAmount) internal {´
Thanx ps how do i get those back ticks around code lol

Comment: Happy to help. If you have multiple discount structure, better break the discount calculation in another function.

Comment: Is it a mess ?```function NoMoreHoops () public payable {
 require minLimitToGetBonus <= 1000;
 require InTime = true;
 uint tokens;

       if ( true) { 
  tokens = msg.value * 4500; \\ +50% during first week if buying min 1000
         }   
         else {
                tokens = msg.value * 3000; \\ No Bonus sry
}
        }

        balances[msg.sender] = safeAdd(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        _totalSupply = safeAdd(_totalSupply, tokens);
        Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokens);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);```

Comment: why there is `if (true)`. Code will always execute this condition and never move to else. Check edit in answer.

Comment: @ Prashant <br/> what about this approach ? pros ,cons with many ifs ?. <br/> ` function getRate ()view return (unit){

if (now > (startTime(1 week))){return 1000}
if (now > (startTime (2 weeks))){return 500} ` <br/>  thx on true issue i learn allot

Comment: It completely depends on your business requires that you want to give a time-based bonus or value-based bonus. Both can be done. There are no special pros and cons. Just get your code correct. Using if and else if instead of if only. And If you find the answer answers your query accept the solution.